# Wordpress php/strtotime issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, time

I am using the Wordpress S2 member Pro plugin which give users an EOT (End of Term) date. Within the database the values are set as timestamps, i.e. 1417564800

In the wordpress user profiles, this would display as 'Wed Dec 3, 2014 12:00 am UTC'

I have added some code which runs when a successful payment has been made. At the top of the code i have the following function:

```
$end = strtotime('+1 years', $timestamp); 
$timestamp = $wp_s2member_auto_eot_time;
```

A bit further down in that code, i want to pull the new date through like this:

```
"s2member_auto_eot_time" => "$end",
```

However, this is pulling in the following date 'Wed Dec 3, 6000 12:00 am UTC' rather than a year ahead of the current date.

Any advice is hugely appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is the code section in its entirity:

```
 <?php

 $end       = mktime(date('h', $timestamp), date('i', $timestamp), date('s', $timestamp), $date('m', $timestamp), date('d', $timestamp), date('Y', $timestamp) + 1);
 $timestamp = $wp_s2member_auto_eot_time;

 $op["op"]      = "create_user"; // The Remote Operation.
 $op["api_key"] = "f4a01f73836f0385f6996a70b372dca3"; // Check your Dashboard for this value.
 // See: `s2Member -› API / Scripting -› Remote Operations API -› API Key`

 $op["data"] = array(
      "user_login" => $my_cookie_variable["username"], // Required. A unique Username. Lowercase alphanumerics/underscores.
      "user_email" => $my_cookie_variable["email"], // Required. A valid/unique Email Address for the new User.

      // These additional details are 100% completely optional.

      "modify_if_login_exists" => "1", // Optional. Update/modify if ``user_login`` value already exists in the database?
      // A non-zero value tells s2Member to update/modify an existing account with the details you provide, if this Username already exists.

      "user_pass" => "", // Optional. Plain text Password. If empty, this will be auto-generated.

      "first_name" => $my_cookie_variable["first"], // Optional. First Name for the new User.
      "last_name" => $my_cookie_variable["last"], // Optional. Last Name for the new User.

      "s2member_level" => "2", // Optional. Defaults to Level 0 (a Free Subscriber).
      "s2member_ccaps" => "", // Optional. Comma-delimited list of Custom Capabilities.

      "s2member_registration_ip" => "", // Optional. User's IP Address. If empty, s2Member will fill this upon first login.

      "s2member_subscr_gateway" => "", // Optional. User's Paid Subscr. Gateway Code. One of: (paypal|alipay|authnet|ccbill|clickbank|google).
      "s2member_subscr_id" => "", // Optional. User's Paid Subscr. ID. For PayPal®, use their Subscription ID, or Recurring Profile ID.

      "s2member_custom" => "www.website.com", // Optional. If provided, should always start with your installation domain name (i.e. $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]).

      "s2member_auto_eot_time" => "$end",

      "custom_fields" => array(
           "title" => $my_cookie_variable["title"],
           "giftaid" => "No",
           "membership_number" => "",
           "tel" => $my_cookie_variable["telephone"],
           "address" => $my_cookie_variable["address1"],
           "towncity" => $my_cookie_variable["city"],
           "county" => $my_cookie_variable["state"],
           "postcode" => $my_cookie_variable["postcode"],
           "country" => $my_cookie_variable["countryshort"],
           "region" => $my_cookie_variable["region"]
      ), // Optional. An array of Custom Registration/Profile Field ID's, with associative values.

      "s2member_notes" => "Administrative notation. Created this User via API call.", // Optional. Administrative notations.

      "opt_in" => "1", // Optional. A non-zero value tells s2Member to attempt to process any List Servers you've configured in the Dashboard area.
      // This may result in your mailing list provider sending the User/Member a subscription confirmation email (i.e. ... please confirm your subscription).

      "notification" => "1" // Optional. A non-zero value tells s2Member to email the new User/Member their Username/Password.
      // The "notification" parameter also tells s2Member to notify the site Administrator about this new account.
 );

 $post_data = stream_context_create(array(
      "http" => array(
           "method" => "POST",
           "header" => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "content" => "s2member_pro_remote_op=" . urlencode(serialize($op))
      )
 ));

 $result = trim(file_get_contents("http://www.website.com/?s2member_pro_remote_op=1", false, $post_data));

 if (!empty($result) && !preg_match("/^Error\:/i", $result) && is_array($user = @unserialize($result)))
      echo "Payment Success - Thank you.";
 else
      echo "API error reads: " . $result;
 ?>
```

Comment: maybe the first two lines of code are switched each other? pls post more code, as it stands it's very difficult to see what's happening

Comment: You're using `$timestamp` before you set it...

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are already a Unix timestamp, why not convert it using that?

```
$time = mktime(date('h',$timestamp),date('i',$timestamp),date('s',$timestamp),$date('m',$timestamp),date('d',$timestamp),date('Y',$timestamp)+1);
echo date('D M d, Y',$time);
```

Comment: Thanks for this - i have added more code as its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to work out the $end value by using $timestamp, on the line before actually setting your $timestamp variable.